# Where does the garbage collector start?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

From what I read, the GC starts at the "root" and follows and marks all the live objects, before the GC runs the sweep. But I am not exactly sure what constitutes the root. For example, in the code below, the Main method starts off a thread and exists. So when GC starts, how does it know which part to select as the root?

```
         static void Main()
         {

             var thread = new Thread(SomeLongRunningProcess);
             thread.Start();

         }

        static void SomeLongRunningProcess()
        {


        }
```

Comment: It would really help if you could explain the underlying problem you're trying to solve, in order words: _why_ do you want to know?

Comment: This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx) explains pretty much everything you need to know about GC. The "The Garbage Collection Algorithm" part is related to your question.

Comment: there's plenty of materials on that topic in the google like this http://www.csharphelp.com/2006/08/garbage-collection/

Comment: Almost any question asked here has an answer in msdn :). The point is can you get your answer for a simple question in a reasonable amount of time? I have given a simple piece of code, someone with a thorough understanding would be able to give a precise answer in a time frame much shorter than the 3 hours I would have to spend reading that article.

Comment: very well, downvoting on StackOverflow means "not showing any research efforts". I don't see any

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Roots include

- static fields (all static fields of all types in all assemblies loaded, for each AppDomain in the process)
- local variables (including those in CPU registers, for each thread)
- the f-reachable queue (a list of objects having a finalizer)
- the finalization queue (a list of objects otherwise garbage, but waiting for finalization)

Comment: 1>Static variables of which object? What if that class has never been called?2> Local variables in the entry point method? 3> I am not sure if List of objects having a finalizer, constitutes as the root. It may end up being a live object, but not necessarily the root.

Comment: I'll be more explicit about the static fields, but I don't understand what you're asking about local variables. All local variables on each stack are roots as soon as they exist, and remain roots until they no longer exist. The f-reachable queue is definitely a root. All objects referenced by it can 't be garbage collected until they have been finalized.

Comment: @Foo You seem to be confused that there is a single root. There is not. There are many objects that qualify as root objects.